# Kafka rest api and a kafka consumer running at the same time, yielding a -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

Essentially the issue is currently i'm sending requests to my kafka rest api on a EC2 instance and that is working fine and saving the data into their relative s3 buckets but in the meanwhile while this is happening if i open another ec2 to check data is sent to the cluster by running a Kafka consumer (one per topic) then i get this warning

*If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N*

When checking

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep ParallelGCThreads
    uintx ParallelGCThreads                         = 0
```

So essentially there are no threads available. So is my thinking correct that all the processors and resources are being used to send the request to my ec2 instance which in turn it to msk cluster and finally sending that with the connector to the s3 bucket